# Make ConnectionResult to a parcelable or serializable object

Tags: android, android-intent, android-location

We can attach a parcelable or serializable object to an intent to send to other activity as below.

intent.putExtra(string, parceable);

I want to send  [ConnectionResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html) but I see ConnectionResult is neither parceable nor serializable.I dont want to use any static field.

Is there any way to make this ConnectionResult to parcelable or serializable ?

Answer (score 0):

ConnectionResult is not parcelable, but it has a constructor that takes an errorCode and a pendingIntent.  Both of those are parcelable.

So, in your service:

```
private void notifyUiFailedConnection(ConnectionResult result) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(FIT_NOTIFY_INTENT);
    intent.putExtra(FIT_EXTRA_NOTIFY_FAILED_STATUS_CODE, result.getErrorCode());
    intent.putExtra(FIT_EXTRA_NOTIFY_FAILED_INTENT, result.getResolution());
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

In your activity:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mFitStatusReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Get extra data included in the Intent
        if (intent.hasExtra(GoogleFitService.FIT_EXTRA_NOTIFY_FAILED_STATUS_CODE) &&
                intent.hasExtra(GoogleFitService.FIT_EXTRA_NOTIFY_FAILED_STATUS_CODE)) {
            //Recreate the connection result
            int statusCode = intent.getIntExtra(GoogleFitService.FIT_EXTRA_NOTIFY_FAILED_STATUS_CODE, 0);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(GoogleFitService.FIT_EXTRA_NOTIFY_FAILED_INTENT);
            ConnectionResult result = new ConnectionResult(statusCode, pendingIntent);
            fitHandleFailedConnection(result);
        }
    }
};
```